# Is there some lightweight alternative to boost::basic_managed_shared_memory?

Tags: c++, memory, boost, shared, managed

I'm looking for lightweight alternative to boost::interprocess::managed_memory_segments.

I just need to be able to allocate and open a couple of named memory segments for IPO from C++ in a nice and relatively portable (Unix&Linux) way. Boost kinda works, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html but it brings huge dependencies (and even bugs in older boost versions) so I don't want it any more.   I don't need any synchronization whatsoever.

Any ideas? Aside from doing it directly from C?

Comment: For what its worth, I had a lot of issues with the boost IPC constructs. I ended up using the native shmem API.